# Hive: Create External Table Partitioned with directory after partition (declared in Location)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have this directory where the data are dumped:

```
"/externallocation/data/20191123/foo_table/part-00000.orc"
```

I need to create a external table, pointed to that directory refered above.
The below statement creates the table, but the query not work as expected (no record is returned):

```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_table (a_column string, b_column boolean)
PARTITIONED BY (year_month_day_key string)
STORED AS ORC LOCATION '/externallocation/data';

> SELECT * FROM foo_table WHERE year_month_day_key = '20191123';
```

Could somone now what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your file path is wrong. The correct file path structure for Hive is as as follow - /warehouse_dir/table_name/partition_column/orc_file.orc. But in your case table is inside partition but partition has to be inside table.

Comment: Hi @AbhinavSingh, thanks for your answer. Sure that the path is not canonical. But  would you know if there are some way to create a external table, with a partition and somehow, Hive infering that the ORC files is in a subfolder? Or another param that could lead Hive "see" those files? Or you think the best way is to turn the path as a canonical?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution -

**File already exists on the HDFS directory** "/user/hive/warehouse/schema.db/foo_table/year_month_day_key=20191123/000000_0"

**Now Create Table**
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema.foo_table
(a_column string,
b_column int)
PARTITIONED BY (year_month_day_key string)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/schema.db/foo_table';

**Partition needs to be added after table creation through below Alter command**
ALTER TABLE schema.foo_table ADD PARTITION (year_month_day_key = '20191123');

select * from schema.foo_table where year_month_day_key = '20191123';

select * from schema.foo_table;